# APM Accelerometer Calibration

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, ardupilot

I am trying to manually calibrate the on-board accelerometer of an APM 2.6 controller.

I am using the following code (I found this somewhere, don't remember where) with Arduino 1.0.5 (in Windows environment) to fetch the accelerometer and gyro data:

```
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <math.h>

  #define ToD(x) (x/131)
  #define ToG(x) (x*9.80665/16384)

  #define xAxis 0
  #define yAxis 1
  #define zAxis 2

  #define Aoffset 0.8

  int time=0;
  int time_old=0;

  const int ChipSelPin1 = 53;

  float angle=0;
  float angleX=0;
  float angleY=0;
  float angleZ=0;



  void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);  

     pinMode(40, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(40, HIGH);


     SPI.begin();  
     SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16); 

     SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST); 
     SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);


      pinMode(ChipSelPin1, OUTPUT);

     ConfigureMPU6000();  // configure chip
    }

void loop()

{
 Serial.print("Acc X ");


  Serial.print(AcceX(ChipSelPin1));
  Serial.print("   ");
  Serial.print("Acc Y ");
  Serial.print(AcceY(ChipSelPin1));
  Serial.print("   ");
  Serial.print("Acc Z ");  
  Serial.print(AcceZ(ChipSelPin1));  
  Serial.print(" Gyro X ");  
  Serial.print(GyroX(ChipSelPin1)); 
  Serial.print(" Gyro Y ");  
  Serial.print(GyroY(ChipSelPin1)); 
  Serial.print(" Gyro Z ");  
  Serial.print(GyroZ(ChipSelPin1)); 
  Serial.println();
}


void SPIwrite(byte reg, byte data, int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t dump;
  digitalWrite(ChipSelPin,LOW);
  dump=SPI.transfer(reg);
  dump=SPI.transfer(data);
  digitalWrite(ChipSelPin,HIGH);
}


uint8_t SPIread(byte reg,int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t dump;
  uint8_t return_value;
  uint8_t addr=reg|0x80;
  digitalWrite(ChipSelPin,LOW);
  dump=SPI.transfer(addr);
  return_value=SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite(ChipSelPin,HIGH);
  return(return_value);
}


int AcceX(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t AcceX_H=SPIread(0x3B,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t AcceX_L=SPIread(0x3C,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t AcceX=AcceX_H<<8|AcceX_L;
  return(AcceX);
}


int AcceY(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t AcceY_H=SPIread(0x3D,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t AcceY_L=SPIread(0x3E,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t AcceY=AcceY_H<<8|AcceY_L;
  return(AcceY);
}


int AcceZ(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t AcceZ_H=SPIread(0x3F,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t AcceZ_L=SPIread(0x40,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t AcceZ=AcceZ_H<<8|AcceZ_L;
  return(AcceZ);
}


int GyroX(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t GyroX_H=SPIread(0x43,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t GyroX_L=SPIread(0x44,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t GyroX=GyroX_H<<8|GyroX_L;
  return(GyroX);
}


int GyroY(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t GyroY_H=SPIread(0x45,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t GyroY_L=SPIread(0x46,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t GyroY=GyroY_H<<8|GyroY_L;
  return(GyroY);
}


int GyroZ(int ChipSelPin) {
  uint8_t GyroZ_H=SPIread(0x47,ChipSelPin);
  uint8_t GyroZ_L=SPIread(0x48,ChipSelPin);
  int16_t GyroZ=GyroZ_H<<8|GyroZ_L;
  return(GyroZ);
}


//--- Function to obtain angles based on accelerometer readings ---//
float AcceDeg(int ChipSelPin,int AxisSelect) {
  float Ax=ToG(AcceX(ChipSelPin));
  float Ay=ToG(AcceY(ChipSelPin));
  float Az=ToG(AcceZ(ChipSelPin));
  float ADegX=((atan(Ax/(sqrt((Ay*Ay)+(Az*Az)))))/PI)*180;
  float ADegY=((atan(Ay/(sqrt((Ax*Ax)+(Az*Az)))))/PI)*180;
  float ADegZ=((atan((sqrt((Ax*Ax)+(Ay*Ay)))/Az))/PI)*180;
  switch (AxisSelect)
  {
    case 0:
    return ADegX;
    break;
    case 1:
    return ADegY;
    break;
    case 2:
    return ADegZ;
    break;
  }
}


//--- Function to obtain angles based on gyroscope readings ---//
float GyroDeg(int ChipSelPin, int AxisSelect) {
  time_old=time;
  time=millis();
  float dt=time-time_old;
  if (dt>=1000)
  {
    dt=0;
  }
  float Gx=ToD(GyroX(ChipSelPin));
  if (Gx>0 && Gx<1.4)
  {
    Gx=0;
  }
  float Gy=ToD(GyroY(ChipSelPin));
  float Gz=ToD(GyroZ(ChipSelPin));
  angleX+=Gx*(dt/1000);
  angleY+=Gy*(dt/1000);
  angleZ+=Gz*(dt/1000);
  switch (AxisSelect)
  {
    case 0:
    return angleX;
    break;
    case 1:
    return angleY;
    break;
    case 2:
    return angleZ;
    break;
  }
}


void ConfigureMPU6000()
{
  // DEVICE_RESET @ PWR_MGMT_1, reset device
  SPIwrite(0x6B,0x80,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // TEMP_DIS @ PWR_MGMT_1, wake device and select GyroZ clock
  SPIwrite(0x6B,0x03,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // I2C_IF_DIS @ USER_CTRL, disable I2C interface
  SPIwrite(0x6A,0x10,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // SMPRT_DIV @ SMPRT_DIV, sample rate at 1000Hz
  SPIwrite(0x19,0x00,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // DLPF_CFG @ CONFIG, digital low pass filter at 42Hz
  SPIwrite(0x1A,0x03,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // FS_SEL @ GYRO_CONFIG, gyro scale at 250dps
  SPIwrite(0x1B,0x00,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);

  // AFS_SEL @ ACCEL_CONFIG, accel scale at 2g (1g=8192)
  SPIwrite(0x1C,0x00,ChipSelPin1);
  delay(150);
}
```

My objective use to calibrate the accelerometers (and gyro), so that I can use them without having to depend on Mission Planner.

I'm reading values like:

```
Acc X 288   Acc Y -640   Acc Z 16884 Gyro X -322 Gyro Y 26 Gyro Z 74
Acc X 292   Acc Y -622   Acc Z 16854 Gyro X -320 Gyro Y 24 Gyro Z 79
Acc X 280   Acc Y -626   Acc Z 16830 Gyro X -328 Gyro Y 23 Gyro Z 71
Acc X 258   Acc Y -652   Acc Z 16882 Gyro X -314 Gyro Y 22 Gyro Z 78
Acc X 236   Acc Y -608   Acc Z 16866 Gyro X -321 Gyro Y 17 Gyro Z 77
Acc X 238   Acc Y -642   Acc Z 16900 Gyro X -312 Gyro Y 26 Gyro Z 74
Acc X 226   Acc Y -608   Acc Z 16850 Gyro X -321 Gyro Y 26 Gyro Z 68
Acc X 242   Acc Y -608   Acc Z 16874 Gyro X -325 Gyro Y 27 Gyro Z 69
Acc X 236   Acc Y -576   Acc Z 16836 Gyro X -319 Gyro Y 19 Gyro Z 78
Acc X 232   Acc Y -546   Acc Z 16856 Gyro X -321 Gyro Y 24 Gyro Z 68
Acc X 220   Acc Y -624   Acc Z 16840 Gyro X -316 Gyro Y 30 Gyro Z 77
Acc X 252   Acc Y -594   Acc Z 16874 Gyro X -320 Gyro Y 19 Gyro Z 59
Acc X 276   Acc Y -622   Acc Z 16934 Gyro X -317 Gyro Y 34 Gyro Z 69
Acc X 180   Acc Y -564   Acc Z 16836 Gyro X -320 Gyro Y 28 Gyro Z 68
Acc X 250   Acc Y -596   Acc Z 16854 Gyro X -329 Gyro Y 33 Gyro Z 70
Acc X 220   Acc Y -666   Acc Z 16888 Gyro X -316 Gyro Y 19 Gyro Z 71
Acc X 278   Acc Y -596   Acc Z 16872 Gyro X -307 Gyro Y 26 Gyro Z 78
Acc X 270   Acc Y -642   Acc Z 16898 Gyro X -327 Gyro Y 28 Gyro Z 72
Acc X 260   Acc Y -606   Acc Z 16804 Gyro X -308 Gyro Y 31 Gyro Z 64
Acc X 242   Acc Y -650   Acc Z 16906 Gyro X -313 Gyro Y 31 Gyro Z 78
Acc X 278   Acc Y -628   Acc Z 16898 Gyro X -309 Gyro Y 22 Gyro Z 67
Acc X 250   Acc Y -608   Acc Z 16854 Gyro X -310 Gyro Y 23 Gyro Z 75
Acc X 216   Acc Y -634   Acc Z 16814 Gyro X -307 Gyro Y 27 Gyro Z 83
Acc X 228   Acc Y -604   Acc Z 16904 Gyro X -326 Gyro Y 17 Gyro Z 75
Acc X 270   Acc Y -634   Acc Z 16898 Gyro X -320 Gyro Y 31 Gyro Z 77
```

From what I understand, SPIread(...,...) returns an analog voltage value from the data pins of the sensor, which happens to be proportional to the acceleration values. Right?

**My question is:** How do I go about calibrating the accelerometer?

**What I've tried till date:** I've tried the "place horizontal... place nose down... left side, right side" technique used by mission planner.

Basically, when placed on horizontal position, the sensor is experiencing +1g on it's Z axis and 0g in X and Y axis. Left/right side provides ±1g on Y axis and nose down/up provides ±1g on X axis.

Now for every orientation, I've passed the raw sensor data through a LPF and then computed the mean, median and SD of this sensor data over 100 iterations. I store this mean, median and SD value in the EEPROM for each axis (one for +1g and one for 0g).

Now, when I use the sensor, I load the stats from the EEPROM, match the mean/median and standard deviation with the current reading of 4/5 iterations.

Here I'm working under the assumption that the values between 0g and +1g (and anything above 1g) can be interpolated/extrapolated from the data using a linear plot.

- Is this the correct approach for calibration?
- Can you suggest a better way?
- I noticed that the maxima/minima for each axis is different. Is this
  the expected outcome or is there something wrong in the code?
- What do I do with the gyro? How to calibrate for angular
  acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use least square approach and solve this problem using Gauss-Newton method. Following blog post sums it up very well.

http://chionophilous.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/accelerometer-calibration-iii-improving-accuracy-with-least-squares-and-the-gauss-newton-method/

Comment: I love people who document their work in elaborate blogs. :) Gauss Newton would be a nice approach, trying that next...